# angular material autocomplete - how to display a specified property of selected object

Tags: angular, autocomplete, angular-material

I have a simple usecase where I loop over an array of objects.

I want to display the property "customName" to the input field but also be able to retrieve its id value for http calls.

```js
<input clrInput [(ngModel)]="order.customer" name="customer [matAutocomplete]="customerAutoComplete"/>
<mat-autocomplete #customerAutoComplete="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="onSelectCustomer($event)">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let customer of customerList" [value]="customer">
        {{customer.customName}}
    </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

When I bind the object to the value, I can retrieve the entire object with optionSelected. But the input will display [Object object] as expected.

When I bind customer.customName to value, I get the string displayed, but don't have any access to the objects id.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `displayWith`

```
<input clrInput [(ngModel)]="order.customer" name="customer [matAutocomplete]="customerAutoComplete"/>
<mat-autocomplete #customerAutoComplete="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="onSelectCustomer($event)" [displayWith]="displayProperty">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let customer of customerList" [value]="customer">
        {{customer.customName}}
    </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

In component.ts

```
public displayProperty(value) {
    if (value) {
      return value.customName;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! Must've missed it in the doc

Answer (score -1):

I use reactive forms, and at the time of assigning the value as you do because it does not select it when I load the api data.